# Updating Entity Framework entity is failing because of relational Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have this structure.

```
Question ---< Answer
--------      ------
Id            Id
Text          Value
```

I am attempting to update the value of Answer by getting it by `Id` from the `DbContext` setting the value to something new and then calling `SaveChanges`.

This is failing stating that question is required. I have the navigational property on `Answer` virtual.

For some reason EF thinks that I want the question to be null. If I set a breakpoint and lazy load the question in then it all works fine.

I only want to update the value, will I need to eager load the question?
If so this seems odd to me.

#### Addendum

There is a `[Required]` Data Annotation on Question in the Answer entity which seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: you don't need to load "Question" to update the "Answer", probably there is something wrong in your mapping. Provide the full structure of `Question` and `Answer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, that's how it works. If your navigation property is not nullable, save will fail until you load it. You have 2 solutions:

1. If you have navigation property `virtual Question Question { get; set; }`
   you should also add `int QuestionID { get; set; }` so when you load your    `Answer` you will have QuestionID value set, and it means your Question can be null, because QuestionID information is enough.
2. If you don't have `context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;` and have `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;` then when you change something on `Answer` the save changes will only update changed values, not the other ones, so the null property wont be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In this case I found that the `[Required]` was not actually needed on the Question and removing it solved the problem.